# Get points of sphere in 3d list python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, 3d, trigonometry

How would I get the points of a sphere with the radius r? Im looking for something like bresenham's circle drawing algorithm but in 3d. I tried just using the 2d algorithm and drawing circles in increasing sizes behind each other, but that doesnt quite work.

[image]

(The picture is distorted around the edges. Thats normal.)

Do you know of anything that could fix that? I could draw a nother smaler circle inside of the bigger one, but thats cheating. Yes, I went through the existing Questions but couldnt find any that fit my purpose.

**Edit:**

```
def drawCircle(self, xyz, r):
        xc, yc, zc = xyz
        coords = []
        
        def drawC(xc, yc, zc, x, y):
            coords.append((xc+x, yc+y, zc))
            coords.append((xc-x, yc+y, zc))
            coords.append((xc+x, yc-y, zc))
            coords.append((xc-x, yc-y, zc))
            coords.append((xc+y, yc+x, zc))
            coords.append((xc-y, yc+x, zc))
            coords.append((xc+y, yc-x, zc))
            coords.append((xc-y, yc-x, zc))
            
        x = 0
        y = r
        d = 3 - 2 * r
        drawC(xc, yc, zc, x, y) 
        while y >= x:
            x += 1
            if (d > 0):
                y -= 1 
                d = d + 4 * (x - y) + 10 
            else:
                d = d + 4 * x + 6
            drawC(xc, yc, zc, x, y) 
        
        for c in coords:
            self.drawPixel(c)
        return coords
```

This function takes a x,y,z point and a radius, calculates all points on the circle and draws them into a 3d array, witch can be drawn to the screen by another function. Here is an example with r = 10. (The circle is pink. Im just testing color.) Im looking or a version without np if possible.

[image: pic]

Comment: Could you please upload your array? I am slightly confused about your problem. You want to spot the sphere in an array and find the points of the sphere in this array?

Comment: No. I want to "draw" a sphere into an array. Ill add how I draw a circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a centered sphere by using the code below.

```
import numpy as np


r=2
y,x,z = np.ogrid[-r:r+1, -r:r+1, -r:r+1,]
mask = x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= r**2

print(mask)
```